# Prove: A linear space generated by finitely many vectors is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Suppose that $M$ is a linear subspace of $X$ generated by finitely many vectors. Prove that $M$ is a closed subspace.

The definition of closed subspace that I learn is if $\bar{M} = M$, where $\bar{M} = \{x \in X: x = lim_{n \to \infty} m_n \text{for some sequence}, m_n \in M, n = 1,2,3,,, \}$ then $M$ is called a closed subspace. How to prove this claim?

Comment: (1) Every normed finite dimensional space is a Banach space. (2) If a subset of a normed space is a Banach space, then it is closed.

Comment: @azif00, doesn't invocation of those facts trivialize the question in a not-so-interesting way? I'd think that the question is asking for a proof of a special case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider $M=$span$\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$, and let $w=\lim_{n \to \infty} w_n$ with $w\in X$ and $w_n \in M$, our goal is to prove that $w\in M$. One possible strategy is to write $w_m=\lambda_{1,m}v_1+...+\lambda_{n,m}v_n$, we can observe that if $w_m$ converges, then $\lambda_{q,m}$ Cauchy converges for all $q \in \{1,...,n\}$ (this has to be rigorously be proved).

Then we can use the fact that the real line (or the complex plane, wherever the $\lambda_{q,m}$ live) is complete, so for every  $q \in \{1,...,n\}$ must exist a $\lambda_{q}$ such that $\lim_{m \to \infty}\lambda_{q,m}=\lambda_{q}$.

Finally we show that $w=\lambda_{1}v_1+...+\lambda_{n}v_n$ (again, this has to be proved rigorously and it should take some time), so we can conclude that $w\in M$.